# Украинский "поребрик"

Tags: диалекты

Во время штурма горотдела МВД в Краматорске один из штурмующих употребил слово "*поребрик*". По заверениям многих представителей СМИ и блогосферы подобное слово на Украине никогда не употребляют.
 В связи с этим вопрос: насколько справедливы подобные утверждения?

И дополнительный вопрос: *какое наименование для обозначения "бордюра"-"поребрика"-"бровки" используют в вашем регионе?* В Вологде называют и "бордюром", и "поребриком", но последним чаще.

**Вопрос касается исключительно ареала распространения слова поэтому просьба воздержаться от политических оценок.**

Comment: Cчитается,  что  поребрик  слово  питерское. А  оказывается,  что  и  в  Вологде  оно  в  ходу.  В  Иркутске - бордюр.  Иркутск-городок  -  Москвы  уголок.

Comment: @МаркИз  Поребрик vs. бордюр: в филологическом споре двух столиц поставят... памятник: https://topspb.tv/news/news121232/. Символично.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На Лингве переломали массу копий.
Ссылки дать не могу, подфорум политический, а потому закрытый. 
Своими словами.

Перво-наперво. Поребрик прежде всего - сам бордюрный камень в профессиональной терминологии. Но в этом значении в быту используется крайне редко.

Далее. В нужном значении "поребрик" тоже выступает в двух ипостасях. В значении собственно уложенного на улице камня: 1) как **граница** проезжей части и возвышающегося над ней тротуара и 2) как собственно эта **тротуарная часть**. Последнее видимо, редко, хотя для меня привычно. И еще это значение совпадает по смыслу с тем, каковое используется в автогонках - специальное покрытие за границей трассы.

Скорее всего в известном ролике было использовано именно это значение - встать на тротуар, за "поребрик". Что уже само по себе вызвало недоумение окружающих. Плюс акцент, подробности не могу точно сказать (три момента было. Г, безударное О и еще что-то).

Ну и по географии.
Современные реалии не дают возможность привязать слово к какому-то региону. Миграция людей и миграция диалектов очевидна.   
Тем не менее.
Поребрик - слово питерское, с этим согласились.
С другой стороны, почти нет мест, где этого поребрика совсем не знают - как и тех, где его употребляют.
Славянск (и Краматорск), несмотря на то, что это Донецкая область, диалектно принадлежит к т.н. Слободской Украине с центром в Харькове. Старые харьковчане о "поребрике" не слыхивали. Но там масса приезжих, утверждать наверняка что-то трудно. 
Скорее всего и в Славянске-Краматорске - тоже.    
Донецкие с большим трудом слово вспомнили.
Алтай, Омск, Одесса - поребрик не используют.
Утверждали, что в Красноярске - поребрик, но не очень уверенно.
Это то, что запомнил, там километры дискуссий, найти сложно.

Comment: Согласен  с  вами.

Comment: Я это не со мной. Я только за Москву и отчасти Харьков отвечаю. Отсальное - коллективный разум.

Answer (score 3):

Украинский? 
Слышали, наверное, расхожее выражение: "В Москве бордюр, а в Питере поребрик", но как я был удивлён услышать "поребрик" от седовласого бригадира Узбека на стройке в Узбекистане не далеко от Уч-Кудука. Он заверил, что никогда не был в РФ и это слово употребляет не менее 20 лет. Про бордюр и поребрик пояснил, что это лишь различные способы укладки.

добавил: В Миассе, Челябинске, Екатеринбурге, Сургуте слово "поребрик" употребляют редко, но тем не менее практически все знают что это такое. Бишкек, Астана, Караганда не слышали и не знают.
Внесу свои пять копеек (да простят меня москвичи)- полагаю, что употребление слова "поребрик" сильно зависит от уровня интеллекта и размера словарного запаса в ежедневном обиходе, ну и конечно от того относит ли себя индивид к действительной интеллигенции или хотя бы общается с интеллигентами.

Comment: Последствия  профобразования.

Comment: Москвичи то может и простят... А вообще кто их знает. Тут не поняла: кто не говорит "поребрик", тот не интеллигент?%( Первый раз я услышала это слово на спортивном жаргоне - это плоские рифленые  плиты, которыми выложены края поворотов на гоночном треке. Так пилоты чувствуют, когда выкатываются за радиус поворота.

Comment: Карусель, я так прямо не выражался, читайте внимательно - моё мнение касательно только поребрика. Тем не менее, прошу простить меня, если чем-то вас обидел.