# Укор (р. п., мн. ч.)

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

Есть ли в русском языке возможность употребить слово «укор» как множественное число в родительном падеже? Похоже, речь идёт о неком поэтическо-возвышенном слоге.

Примеры из поиска:

*«К свободе от укор его»*

*«И получу теперь свободу От времени и от укор»*

*«прячась будто, от укор Зимы»*

Comment: А зачем запятая после "будто"?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой это вопрос к автору: "Что летит, к бордюрам прижимаясь, прячась будто, от укор Зимы".

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova если правка явно противоречит намерениям автора (пусть в этих намерениях есть ошибка), лучше ее не вносить, а указать на неточность в ответе/комментарии.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95380/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В толковом словаре:
[УКО́РА](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-36382.htm), -ы, **ж.** (*стар.*). То же, что укор. *Быль молодцу **не укора.*** (Пословица о том, что не следует винить кого-нибудь за старые грехи, ошибки.)

*О, не тревожь меня **укорой** справедливой* (Тютчев).
*Клюка **не укора**, да сума нехороша* (пословица).

В поэтических примерах, указанных Вами, использовано устаревшее слово **уко́ра**, имеющее женский род. Склоняем: уко́ры (мн. ч., И. п.) — уко́р (мн. ч., Р. п.).
[Сравните: шпо́ра — шпо́ры — шпо́р.]

Один из фрагментов, думаю, взят вот из этих стихов (пунктуация авторская — не комментирую, не исправляю).

*...Ведь Зима, совсем не за горами,

так не хочется, тепло сейчас терять

Бабье Лето, быстро пробегает,

и тепло то будем, целый год мы ждать*

*Солнце, словно с осенью прощаясь,

заискрится, в красках той листвы

Что летит, к бордюрам прижимаясь,

[прячась будто, от укор Зимы...](http://www.playcast.ru/view/3386298/1c3ec292094bc060057735070afa4c3a86d59369pl)*

Comment: Что летит, с поребриком равняясь :) Бордюр - бумажная полоска вдоль верхнего края обоев.

Comment: Не могу с Вами согласиться. _В дорожном строительстве — узкие полосы (бортовые камни, плиты), отделяющие проезжую часть дороги от тротуаров._ https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-encycl-term-9095.htm На нашем сайте: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32507/Украинский-поребрик.

Comment: Технические термины (да, встречается "бордюрный камень", но и сама терминология спорна: бордюрами французы именовали "плоско" вкопанные границы проезжей части, а не выступы) в поэтических текстах не смотрятся, региональное же восприятие поребриков ограничивается местами, куда ступала нога бонапартиста :)